# Get a remote picture cause NetworkOnMainThreadException in android

Tags: android, facebook, get, image

First, sorry for my poor english.

I'm trying to create a simple android app that connect to Facebook using official Facebook API. When a user login and authorize my app, I want to fetch his/her username and profile picture, and then display in my app. I've adopted some code from Hackbook sample app that came with Facebook API. Here's my code in main activity class.

```
public class SocialApp2Activity extends Activity {
    private Handler handler;

    private Facebook facebook;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner;

    private TextView text;
    private ImageView imgUserPic;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        handler = new Handler();

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        imgUserPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_pic);

        facebook = new Facebook("MY_FB_APP_ID");
        asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("fields", "name, picture");
                asyncRunner.request("me", params, new UserRequestListener());
            }

            ... 

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    /* Callback for fetching username and profile picture */
    public class UserRequestListener implements RequestListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {

            JSONObject jsonObject;

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                final String picURL = jsonObject.getString("picture");
                final String name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        text.setText(name);

                        /********************************
                         *** This line cause an error ***
                         ********************************/
                        imgUserPic.setImageBitmap(Utility.getBitmap(picURL));

                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I get an error on calling my own method that read bitmap data of profile picture from remote server. The error is NetworkOnMainThreadException and some of a stack trace is here.

```
05-04 14:37:28.898: W/System.err(1117): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-04 14:37:28.905: W/System.err(1117):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
05-04 14:37:28.905: W/System.err(1117):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
...
05-04 14:37:29.005: W/System.err(1117):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
05-04 14:37:29.005: W/System.err(1117):     at promlert.socialapp2.Utility.getBitmap(Utility.java:26)
05-04 14:37:29.016: W/System.err(1117):     at promlert.socialapp2.SocialApp2Activity$UserRequestListener$1.run(SocialApp2Activity.java:95)
...
```

Could you please advice me how to workaround this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handler.post(Runnable runnable) is executing the runnable on the UI thread.  so if you are trying to perform network operation on the UI thread - you'll get this exception. to avoid this: call first the Utility.getBitmap(picURL) not from the UI thread, and then post on the UI thread only the imgUserPic.setImageBitmap() method :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //this line must be called not from the UI  thread
                final Bitmap bitmap = Utility.getBitmap(picURL)
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                                   text.setText(name);
                                   imgUserPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap );

                                  }
                  });   
                }
}).start();
```

Comment: The `Utility` class is `internal.facebook.Utility`, right? It says it has no function like `getBitmap`

Comment: @rockydgeekgod:  yes. a least it was at the time of the post